# Order of Attributes in HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I know it doesn't matter what order you put attributes in an HTML tag, but I maintain a consistent pattern for readability/debugging reasons. However, I'm going to need to violate my pattern because I need to add an onmouseover to a bunch of elements using find/replace. My mouseover will call a javascript function and will pass the id as a variable. I will be placing this function before the element's id attribute. Will this cause any problems with some browsers? I just want to be sure that every modern browser reads all of an element's attributes before executing scripts.

Comment: As you said, it doesn't matter, :)

Comment: it does not matter,

why not try for 1 thing and test in 4 browsers in 60 sec rather than typing so much text.

Comment: I don't have older versions of IE, etc

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that the order or attributes in HTML does not matter and therefore you will not experience any problems with having `onmouseover` before the `id` attribute.